# Axios promises confusion

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I'm confused how I keep getting Test1's result for all the other info indexes, so if Test1 is true, the it'll keep printing true based on Test1 even if Test2 and Test3 is null

```
let info = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"];

isInfoAviable= (email) => {
    payload.info = info
    return axios.post(url, payload, axiosConfig).then((response) => {
        return response.data.isAvailable ? true : null
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

for (info of infos) {

    isInfoAviable(info).then((res) => {
        console.log(res) // If Test1 returns true, it'll  true even if Test2 is null, why?
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `catch` the error in the `isInfoAviable` function, so when you execute `isInfoAviable()`, it'll be resolved even if the promise is rejected in `isInfoAviable`.

To resolve this, remove the `catch` from `isInfoAviable` and catch it when you call `isInfoAviable()` instead:

```
isInfoAviable(info).then(...).catch(...)
```

**EDIT**: change `payload.info = info` to `payload.info = email`. Also avoid using variables outside of the scope of the function (eg. `payload` should be declared in `isInfoAviable`).

Comment: I removed the catch from isInfoAvailable and put it in the for loop, like you said and it's still giving the same output

Comment: ok maybe I'm not understanding your problem. "If Test1 returns true, it'll  true" what will be true?

Comment: If I put a console.log(payload.info) in the axios.post(() => {}), then payload.info always will return Test1, without checking the others

Comment: And Test1 is true, so if I reorder the array to ["Test3", "Test1", "Test2"] it'll still only print Test1

Comment: Oh, try `payload.info =  email`. Also try to avoid using variables outside of the scope of the function (eg. `payload` is not declared in `isInfoAviable`).

Comment: Yeah it was email before, this was when I was testing, but even if I do payload.info = email it does the same thing, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Can you paste your actual code? Is `let info = ...` supposed to be `let infos = ...`? Add in the code where you did `console.log`.

Comment: The declaration of payload inside the function fixed everything.